# OSGI fragment not loading in production environment

Tags: eclipse, osgi, fragment

I have a third party library which I loaded in a fragment, and coupled it to system.bundle, because it needs to be loaded in the root class path. In the development environment the code runs fine, but when I deploy it in a production environment, I get a ClassNotFoundException. The bundle that uses the fragment is started without problems, so I am not seeing any unusual behaviour in the list of active bundles, as compared to the IDE. The fragment is 'resolved', but this also applies in the development IDE

Does anyone have a clue to what I can do to investigate this issue further?

The fragment is defined as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: {bundle-name}
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.mybundle.fragment;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.47.0.2
Bundle-Vendor: Condast
Fragment-Host: system.bundle
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ClassPath: {theLibs},
 .
Export-Package: {exported packages}
```

**Edit/Update**

It seems that this problem may actually have something to do with slf4j packages. I've stumbled upon a few similar posts, where slf4j interferes with the system.bundle. I'm looking into it..

Comment: What are the {curly braced} things in the manifest? Is this the actual manifest file from the fragment jar?

Comment: It's the list of bundles and exported packages. That bit is fine